Rotation of a magnetic dipole in an RF field
Lets say I have a magnetic dipole with gyromagnetic ratio $\gamma$ in an RF field $\vec{B_{RF}}=B_{RF}\cos(\omega_{RF}t)\hat{x}$ and ALSO a static field $\vec{B_0}=B_0 \hat{z}$. Using $$\dot{\vec{L}}=\gamma \vec{L} \times \vec{B}$$
Using this, I get
$$\dot{L_{x}}=\gamma B_{0}L_{y}$$
$${\dot{L_{y}}}=\gamma B_{RF} \cos(\omega_{RF}t) L_{z}-\gamma B_{0}L_{x}$$
$${\dot{L_{z}}}=-\gamma B_{RF} \cos(\omega_{RF}t) L_y$$
Using $L_{xy}=L_x+iL_y$ I can "simplify":
${\dot{L_{xy}}}+i\gamma B_{0} L_{xy}=i\gamma B_x L_z$
And using ${\tilde{L_{xy}}}=e^{i\gamma B_{0} t}L_{xy}$
this becomes
$${\dot{\tilde{L_{xy}}}}=i\gamma B_x L_z$$
After spending a lot of time, I was unable to find an analytic solution. However, I used Matlab to solve an example, and found that the transverse magnetization looked surprisingly sinusoidal:

Is there an obvious solution I am not seeing here? My main goal is to find the rotation of the dipole moment onto the transverse plane, but it doesn't look like an analytical solution exists, and it doesn't seem like approximating it is very straightforward unless I am overlooking something.

It would have been easier to see the link using Larmor frequencies:
$$
\omega_0 = \gamma B_0 \quad \Omega_{RF} = \gamma B_{RF}
$$
I will choose the time unit so that $\omega_0=1$. In the rotating frame that you are considering, your magnetic field has the expression:
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}\Omega_{RF}\cos(\omega_{RF}t)\cos t\\
\Omega_{RF}\cos(\omega_{RF}t)\sin t\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
You were further interested in the case $\omega_{RF} = 1$. You can therefore separate the field into a constant part and fast varying part:
$$
B = \frac{\Omega_{RF}}2\begin{pmatrix}1\\
0\\0\end{pmatrix}+\frac{\Omega_{RF}}2\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2t)\\
\sin(2t)\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
The idea is to neglect the second term for the long term dynamic. Indeed, they only matter at timescales of the order $\pi$, whose fluctuations average to zero, but the first one influences much larger timescales of order $4\pi/\Omega_{RF}$. You can verify in your simulation that your $\omega_{calc} = \frac{\Omega_{RF}}2$. You can also verify that at times scales of order $\pi$, the solution is not sinusoidal but is perturbed around it (this is not visible in your current plot as $\Omega_{RF}=5\cdot10^{-3}$).
